# VS Code show 2 repos with same name

Tags: git

Environment: Mint 21.2

VS Code: 1.80.1

'Remote' repo on NAs , access via NFS mount @ /mynas/git/???.git

Git, VSC * Mint newb!

After working with some other git GUIs - SmartGit mostly - I ran into issues of not being able to push to the 'remote'

Opening the code base in VSC, and looking at the git panel, it looks like VSC finds 2 repos with the same name.
Right now I am stumped as to how to best proceed without losing any of the current changes in my attempts to rectify these issues.
As far as I can tell, there is only one copy of this directory on my machine.

My main interest is to resolve the issue of pushing to my remote.
In the process, I also hope to get to know and understand the VSC  Git interface better as well as Git in general.